# PHP include is not including existing file content

Tags: php, codeigniter

In application/config.php I have a include function like so

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/log.php');
```

or

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/session.php');
```

obviously my config files are in root/config/whatever.php. Now since I moved my files to a new server the include is not working probably. so if I write the name of the file I'll get an error but if the file exists its not going to include the constant of it and CI through error such as

> In order to use the Session class you are required to set an
>   encryption key in your config file.

as a solution I can actually include the contact the file in config.php (but that's not what I want to do since I use the came details in several separate CI applications). so I appreciate any better solution.

Many Thanks in advance

p.s. I'm using PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2015 15:23:08)

update:

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/session.php'; ///returns : var/www/html/config/session.php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/session.php'); //return nothing and its not including the vars since i get encryption key error
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/sessionsfgdfgsdf.php'); //gives error
```

Comment: problem was resolved once I put short_open_tag = On; in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurred because ifyou are not using encrypted sessions, you must set an encryption key in your config file which is used to aid in preventing session data manipulation

To save your key to your `application/config/config.php,` open the file and set:

```
$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";
```

Also read [Session Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html/) and [Setting your Key](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html/)

Comment: I understand this Saty but the encryption is in include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/session.php'); its just that php is not including it... it acknowledge that it exist but not including it.

Comment: you an put this file in third_party folder and try to include it

Comment: but I want to have it in root level.

Comment: what path `root/config/whatever.php` is this?? what is root in that??

Comment: try with `include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../config/session.php';
`

Answer (score 0):

in `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['encryption_key'] = "123";
```

To include

```
file_get_contents(APPPATH.'config/session.php');
```

Comment: use `include(APPPATH.'config/session.php')`

Comment: my file is in the root not APPPATH

Comment: root means outside application??

Comment: Yes! my file is here -> var/www/html/config/session.php . include acknowledge that it exists but its not including the constant of it (my other server includes it with no problem).

Comment: try `include(base_url().'config/session.php');`

Comment: base_url returns url ... I need root and $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is doing the right job the problem is with include .... anyway : Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url() in /var/www/html/menu/application/config/config.php on line 170

Comment: go to `config/autload.php` add this `$autoload['helper'] = array('url'');`

Comment: please read this I think it'll help you -> http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Allow_url_include

Comment: @ash No men. In codeigniter thats only way to call a file

Comment: trust me im using include for years now... I think my problem is with php because also i tried to echo something and its not working from inside <? ?> but it works from <?php  ?>

Comment: ya. you need to type `<?php` cz short tag are not allowed. (`<?`)

Comment: i think i found the issue ... its with short_open_tag being off